# Would a bullet damage a piece of metal the same as a pointy stick?

Tags: forces, material-science, speed

If you used a materials that would offer zero bending or dulling (the bullet/ pointy stick), would a 10 g bullet traveling at 1000 m/s with a surface area of 1 mm squared damage a piece of metal the same as a 1000 g pointy stick with the same surface area of 1 mm squared traveling at 10 m/s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While their momenta would be the same the bullet is going to have way more kinetic energy and so do more damage.